# Does istikharah work if you just read it without doing salah?

Tags: salat, istikharah

Does istikharah still work if someone reads the istikharah without doing salah? For example, if someone is sitting on their office desk or if they are reading it before bed. Or does istikharah only work when we do it in salah?

Comment: if you have any question about stress you can ask me on  Instagram- @its_quran_time